# How to color cards (hearts and diamonds) red in Drupal 7 comments?

Tags: 7, nodes, comments

I run a Drupal 7 website with Forum, Blog, Comment core modules enabled and a custom module (generates a block with Flash game and blocks with player rating) written by me.

The website is dedicated to a Russian card game and users often [mention card colors](http://preferans.de/comment/1151#comment-1151) in their comments when discussing some card riddle or a game:

[image]

Most users are older folks, who don't understand anything like HTML tags, so I have only enabled plain text comments for them.

**My quesion is:** in the plain text Comments - how to recognize the strings like K♥ or 7♦ and color them red?

The PHP code would be something like:

```
preg_replace(/(1?[0789JQKA][♥♦])/, '<font color="red">\1</font>', $str);
```

(I can improve the regex later) - but where/how to apply it in Drupal 7?

Comment: OK, why on earth is there an 'off-topic' close vote on _this_ question? Come on people, read the question first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be [Text filters and Input Formats](http://drupal.org/node/213156).

> Processing textual content for output in a browser is one of Drupal's most critical tasks. Without such processing we would all have to become masters at typing in HTML text! This section of the handbook explains what filters and input formats are, why they are important, how they are used, and why they impact site security.

Or you can just dump regex in template.php or comment.tpl.php - it's way simpler and way less clean, but works.

Comment: For an example of how to add an input filter see the http://drupal.org/project/examples module's filter example.

Comment: Also, if you go the filter route with the plain text filter, make sure your filter comes after the plain text filter.

Comment: Your link describes the core filters and formats (I guess I should modify the "Line Break Converter" core filter), but it doesn't explain - which files implement them and how to modify them

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Grab a copy of the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples); it has a fully fledged custom filter example included (filter_example)

Comment: Molot's 2nd suggestion: does it mean, that I should modify the `$content` variable in `themes/bartik/templates/comment.tpl.php` file?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber - Clive was faster than me :) I assumed you will be able to find it once you know what you are looking for. filter_example from Examples for Developers is good. Way less scary than I was afraid it'll be.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber - no no no, you should never modify modules and templates from Drupal's core or from Drupal.org. [Inherit from them](http://drupal.org/node/225125) or fork them and then modify. But I'd only advise it if you really really fail at making filter.

Comment: @Molot, when I (just for testing purpose) try the line `print render($content."TEST");` in the `themes/bartik/templates/comment.tpl.php` file - I get comments with empty bodies.

Comment: @AlexandrFarber Why of course you do, you can't reliably concatenate $content array with "test" string and expect result to be renderable. But that's material for another question, and yet another reason to go filter way.

Comment: Last question please: how to see the content of that array or do you know the name of its string member - for the case of the bad approach? :-)

Comment: Oh come one, first page of Google results for >>php how to see the content of array<< - every position is an answer. Or >>php variable details<<.

Comment: Yes, it is `var_dump()` or `print_r()` - but how to see their output in Drupal?

Comment: @Aleksander Just like in any other app. If in doubt, put a die() just after them. Strictly programming questions should go to stackoverflow (tagged php drupal) and not comments here.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use the `dpm()` function. You'll never go back to `var_dump` :)

Answer (score 5):

If you need it to be configurable/re-usable then a custom filter is the way to go as Mołot said. The idea is that the raw data is always stored, and the filter is applied upon display. This is all well and good, but if you don't ever *need* the original text I find this method to be an unnecessary performance overhead (especially when you involve regexs, as most filters do).

The other way is to intercept the comment body before it's saved, and apply your filter then. For this you can use [`hook_comment_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_presave/7):

```
function MYMODULE_comment_presave($comment) {
  $comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['value'] = string_replacement_function($comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['value']);
}
```

I know this method is 'frowned upon' (heaven forbid we alter someone's input, even if we *want* to control what goes in the database!), and I can think of at least 2 people who will downvote this if/when they see it.

I think the benefits/drawbacks of both methods are pretty clear, though, so I'd advise you make a decision based on *your use-case*. If the module you implement to do this isn't being released back into the wild, I see no benefit in taking the extra performance hit here.

But if you think you'll ever want to use this method to filter text elsewhere on the site (e.g. in node bodies), a custom filter would make more sense.

Comment: This is especially a good solution if users cannot edit their comments after they have commented, because they will never see your altered version of the code, so you never have to undo your alteration of their content.

Comment: @rooby Good point, I didn't think of that

Comment: @rooby - actually it's only a bad solution if they can edit ;) Clive - with good caching it's hardly a performance impact, as filtered text should sit in cache for a long time, possibly until edited. Of course then there is that little difference between "should" and "will"..

Comment: Actually I'd prefer not to modify the stored data. I'd like to modify the displayed (and cached?) data only.

Comment: @Mołot Indeed, mileage will vary with this method. I can see this being a "I just need this to happen in one place" sort of request so I wanted to offer the simpler method as an alternative. The method you've outlined will always be the best practice, most re-usable method without question

Comment: Excellent, then you want the method in @Mołot's answer. It's a bit more code, but fits your use case perfectly. Plus you'll keep the purists happy :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer myself because I like to see many different valid answers. Just wanted to elaborate a tiny bit more on the performance side of the problem. And I must admit that cache fails, gets regenerated etc and is in no way stable. That's what it does, by it's very nature. Your solution avoids it, and that's a good thing.